# htop does not show omp_get_num_threads() cpus occupied, but only 2

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, openmp, cpu, openmpi

I have parallelized, in C++, a doubly-nested for-loop using OpenMP by writing `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(static) firstprivate(...) shared(...)`.

Inside `main()`, I write the MPI-startup commands (program will use 1 process), and I then set `omp_set_num_threads(12)`, by hand.

The doubly nested for-loop when serialized, takes many minutes to run. When parallelized, it is scheduled as `static`.

When I write in the terminal `$ htop`, when the C++ application is running and computing the doubly-nested for-loop, I get the following picture [image: htop]

There is evidence that 12 threads are actually spawned and running from `cout`-ing on the std-output the `omp_get_tread_num()` of each thread in the loop.

From time to time, the CPU's numbered 3 and 4 go to 0.0% utilization and a few (usually 2) others fire up, to a maximum of 9-10 % utilization.

I was expecting to have 12 cores being utilized close to 100% each.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening?

### System/Environment Details:

- WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 on Win11
- Intel (R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90 GHZ
- OpenMP: g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
- MPI: mpirun (Open MPI) 4.0.3

Comment: Give me 5mn to get my crystal ball, so I can see from your code what can possibly go wrong.

Comment: More seriously: have to tried to run a simple toy example, that is a standalone code with only one big and simple OpenMP loop with enough calculations inside, to check if all the expected cores are used or not ?

Comment: You should not call `omp_set_num_threads` manually and let OpenMP use the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable typically set by the HPC job submission tool. If you try to spawn threads the way you do, then threads will likely be bound to core in an inefficient way causing performance issues like the one you can see. Please specify the OpenMP runtime you use and the MPI runtime too. I advise you to check the binding of the spawned threads. I also advise you to try your code on a bare-metal machine since WSL can introduce some additional issues (like having a VERY slow FS).

Comment: Besides, please share the CPU reference of the target platform. If this is a big-little architecture, then I would not be surprise of such problem (especially in WSL). Same with CPUs having NUMA effects, if the unused cores are simply coming from a load balancing issue. Too many information are missing so we can help you.

Comment: I see, thank you both @JérômeRichard @PierU. I didn't post the actual doubly-nested for-loop code as I thought it is too complicated for anyone to read. I will try what PierU said. I will also use the ``OMP_NUM_THREADS`` env variable from now on. I will also try the code on a pure-Unix machine.

Comment: Thank you for the additional infos, AFAIK the i7-10700 CPU is not a big-little one and NUMA effects are not visible on it so the load imbalance is unlikely to come from the CPU itself, but more likely from your code. AFAIK, GOMP (the OpenMP runtime of GCC) does not bind threads to cores. OpenMPI may do it, but I remember it did not by default when I used it on my machine (>5 years ago though) but it is worth checking. You could try a `dynamic` scheduling and check whether the time of the loop is about the same for all threads (with `omp_get_wtime`).

Comment: Could you try launching your code with `mpirun --bind-to none` please?

Comment: I think I found out something: Inside my doubly-nested for loop, I put with ``.at()`` in a ``shared`` ``std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> vec(50)``, at the end of each iteration of the loop, the result calculated in that iteration. I gather that std::vector is not thread safe and the ``.at()`` command screws things up?

Comment: Update for all: with ``export OMP_PLACES=cores && export OMP_PROC_BIND=true && export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12 && mpirun -np 1 ./numerov > output.log`` I do get that 12 processors are full to roughly (update: constant) 100% !!! I am still testing what I am seeing.

Comment: `vector<vector<vector<double>>>` usually sucks for performance vs. an actual 3D array (since it's pointers to pointers to doubles instead of just a multiplication of indices), but as long as it's pre-allocated so you're only using `[]` or `.at()`, no thread is changing any of the pointers, just a pointed-to double.  Unless you mean you're assigning a new `std::vector` as a new row, in which case the pointers do change so it wouldn't be thread-safe.

Comment: Also, doesn't that constructor call `vec(50)` start out with 50 empty `vector<vector<double>>` elements for the outer vector?  So you must be allocating somewhere.  If it's inside the loop, then it won't be parallizable or even SIMD vectorizable.

Comment: Once again, commenting on a code without seeing the code is just wild guesses

Comment: @PeterCordes, I don't know why I used this strange construction of ``vector<vector<vector<double>>>`` when I wrote the code. I think I could equally well use a linear, very long buffer of type ``vector<double>`` and change my indexing mechanism.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you for your useful insights! Indeed, the CTOR call ``vec(50)`` starts with 50 empty ``vector<vector<double>>`` before the loop-iterations start. I allocate the 50 vectors inside the for loop as: ``std::vector<std::vector<double>> results_for_this_k_value;``, each of which is then populated with quite a few instructions of the type ``push_back(to_push_back)``, where ``to_push_back`` is a ``vector<double>``.  At the end of each iteration, I write: ``vec.at(iter) = results_for_this_k_value``. This allocation and population mechanism repeats for every loop-iteration.

Comment: lol, ok, it's not the `.at` that's a problem for finding parallelism, it's the `.push_back`.  (And probably the copy-assignment of a whole `std::vector` rather than just a double).  So yeah, that sounds like a total disaster for OpenMP.  Do one big allocation outside the loop (probably of a flat `std::vector<double>` with manual indexing, since C++ makes runtime-variable dimensions inconvenient, e.g. no VLAs and you can't do `std::array<std::array<double, n>, m>` with non-constant dimenions because it's a template.)